# Lever / rouler les / des yeux au / vers le ciel

Tags: expressions

Bonjour,

> Lever les yeux au ciel.

Est-il possible de dire ***rouler** les yeux au ciel*, *rouler **des** yeux au ciel*, *rouler les yeux **vers** le ciel*, *lever les yeux **vers** le ciel* ?

À mon avis, l'article défini "les" devrait être préférable devant "yeux".

Comment: Rouler des yeux au ciel? On dirait des yeux  "énucléés".

Comment: None et LPH, merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 5):

L'expression c'est *lever les yeux **au** ciel*, ce qui veut dire  montrer de l'agacement. Si quelqu'un « lève les yeux vers le ciel » c'est à prendre au sens propre, c'est à dire que son regard se porte vers le ciel pour, par exemple, voir les nuages pour dire d'où vient le vent ou pour regarder les étoiles.

Et c'est **les** (articles défini), et pas **des** (article indéfini). On pourrait essayer de donner une explication logique en disant que l'emploi de l'article indéfini impliquerait qu'on ne lève qu'une partie des yeux, mais alors pourquoi l'expression avec rouler est-elle *rouler des yeux*. Donc je crois que ce sont des expressions, et c'est comme ça, faut l'accepter. Cependant j'ai trouvé un dictionnaire ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rouler/70054#166578)) qui donne « rouler les yeux », je trouve ça bizarre, maladroit.

C'est donc *rouler des yeux* et si on mentionne le ciel, c'est aussi **au** (pas **vers**). Je dis « si on mentionne le ciel » car on trouve plus fréquemment *rouler des yeux*, que *rouler des yeux au ciel*.

> Certaines répliques et certaines de leurs actions vous ferons rouler les yeux au ciel si fort qu'ils risquent de sortir de leurs orbites. ([Sens Critique](https://www.senscritique.com/film/Star_Wars_L_Ascension_de_Skywalker/critique/208549620))

> moi qui suis du style, comme assesseur, à rouler des yeux au ciel, hausser les épaules, hocher ostensiblement, sourire en coin, ([Le blog d'un avocat](https://www.maitre-eolas.fr/post/2009/03/31/1349-vade-mecum-de-la-comparution-immediate-3))

> rouler des yeux au ciel : Faire les gros yeux, grimacer à l'aide du regard ([Un site tenu par des enseignants](https://www.edumoov.com/fiche-de-preparation-sequence/28392/lecture-et-comprehension-de-l-ecrit/cm2/faire-de-la-grammaire-au-cm2---periode-4-texte-5--le-reve-de-zac)).

On peut d'ailleurs constater que parfois le sens de l'expression varie, selon le cas, entre « montrer de l'étonnement » et « montrer de la réprobation ».

Comment: rouler les yeux au ciel ne prête aucunement à la confusion?

Comment: @Lambie  Non à mon avis pour *rouler **des** yeux (au ciel).  Par contre *rouler **les** yeux* au ciel* me parait encore bizarre et non corroboré par d'autres sources malgré ce que dit le Larousse.  Mais je ne cite que des usages attestés et pas mes propres exemples et ça ne me dérange pas de faire évoluer la langue.

Comment: Pour moi, j'ai l'impression que les yeux sont désincarnés et la personne est au ciel. Du genre: rouler sa bosse à Paris.

Comment: @Lambie  Il n'y a aucune ambiguïté dans les exemples  que j'ai trouvés, on ne peut pas comprendre autrement (avec des, je répète, je n'en ai trouvé aucun avec les - j'ai cherché pourtant).

Comment: Dans des cas comme celui-ci, je pense qu'il faut faire appel à ses  propres connaissances. "Pas tout" est déjà écrit. Si tout était déjà écrit, la creativité n'existerait pas. Vos propres internalisations, disons, me suffisent à moi. Je ne suis pas fanatique des recherches en ligne pour résoudre des usages peu communs.

Answer (score 1):

Tout cela est plutôt compliqué. « Rouler **des** yeux » correspond à deux formes.

Si l'on fait suire « yeux » par une modification, alors on emploie « *des* » et non pas « les ».

- Il roulait des yeux haggards et froids depuis un moment déjà.
- Il roulait des yeux qui en disaient long sur ses intentions.
- Il roulait des yeux comme une soucoupe.

Il ne s'agit pas dans l'usage illustré précédemment de la locution verbale « rouler des yeux », qui est expliquée maintenant.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rouler_des_yeux)) Locution verbale
>
> rouler des yeux \ʁu.le de.z‿jø\ (se conjugue → voir la conjugaison de rouler)
>
> Être étonné, circonspect.
>
> ♦ « La plupart des scientifiques roulent des yeux » face à la décision de certains gouvernements européens, abonde le quotidien de centre gauche The Guardian.

Dans la locution verbale figée (qui ne peut être analysée)  « rouler » serait plutôt intransitif, alors que dans les autres usages « rouler » est transitif.

Lorsque « rouler des yeux » est employé en isolation il s'agit de la locution figée.

- Ils roulent des yeux. (*Cependant « les » et « leurs » sont possibles.*)
- Rouler des yeux peut se faire de toutes sortes de façons. (*« ses », « nos »*)
- Arrêtez de rouler des yeux et mettez-vous au travail. (*« vos », « les »*)

Si l'on fait suivre « yeux » par un complément, alors on peut employer soit « *les* » soit  « des ».

- Il roulait les/des yeux au ciel.
- Il roulait les/des yeux en signe de désapprobation.
- Il roulait les/des yeux à n'en plus finir.
- Il roulait les/des yeux en signe de désapprobation.

« Rouler *les* yeux *au* ciel. (*« vers » semble rare.*)

Il y a un cas de « rouler *les* yeux *vers* le ciel ».
([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Dernier_des_Justes_Prix_Goncourt_1959/s8mPCgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rouler+des+yeux%22&pg=PT68&printsec=frontcover)) Mais quand la pointe du sabre fut à deux doigts de son cou, rejetant la tête en arrière, il plaqua ses bras contre le tronc du sapin et se mit à rouler des yeux furibonds vers le ciel, tandis que sa bouche hurlait les premiers mots de